# heroku deploy fail on autoload files generation

Tags: heroku

Cannot deploy my symfony v4 app to heroku.

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/heroku-roku/deploy/github
https://github.com/rokiszb/symfonyproject

```
   Generating optimized autoload files

   ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...

   ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class

   Executing script cache:clear [KO]

    [KO]

   Script cache:clear returned with error code 255

   !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "WebServerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle".

   !!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/src/Kernel.php:32

   !!  Stack trace:

   !!  #0 /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(403): App\Kernel->registerBundles()

   !!  #1 /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()

   !!  #2 /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()

   !!  #3 /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object in /tmp/build_28117d3324a8922a1e14fe57f3023b59/rokiszb-symfonyproject-da9bd88/src/Kernel.php on line 32
```

been trying to solve it for many hours, need help